# i can't declare a pointer as a global variable

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to run this program that manage login but I have a problem with declaring this pointer as a global variable , the error that it shows me is 
"initializer element is not constant"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    char nom_utilisateur[20];
    char mot_de_passe[20];
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
}USER;


 USER *u =(USER *)malloc(sizeof(USER)*20);

int nbr_usr=0;
void adduser() {};
 ......
```

Comment: It is not the declaration by itself but the initialization that you are providing. In C, code outside functions cannot be executed, you'd have to put that `malloc` inside a function. (And don''t cast the return of `malloc`)

Comment: You need to have a `main()`.

Comment: Also please, go through the help pages to learn how to ask questions. We usually need more information about what you are doing. In particular a whole minimal code example.

Answer (score 2):

In C you cannot call functions during initialisation of global variables.

You need to do the initialisation for example in `main`:

```
...
USER *u;
...
int main()
{
   u = malloc(sizeof(USER)*20);
   ...
}
```

BTW:

1. you don't need to cast the result of `malloc`.
2. the variable name `u` is not a good idea. Give it a meaningful name, e.g. `users`.

Not directly related to your question, but be aware that the `20` in the struct declaration below is not at all related to the `20` in `malloc(sizeof(USER)*20)`.

```
typedef struct {
    char nom_utilisateur[20];
    char mot_de_passe[20];
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
} USER;
```

in this `struct` declaration the `20` means that each user's password, nom, prenom etc. can have a length of 19 at most, 19 because strings are NUL terminated.

The `20` in `malloc(sizeof(USER)*20)` means that you can have at most 20 users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the declaration.
The problem is that you are initializating the pointer with a runtime information. 
Think about `malloc` as something that can only be executed when the program is actually running. Such stuff must be placed in a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    char nom_utilisateur[20];
    char mot_de_passe[20];
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
}USER;


 USER *u;

int nbr_usr=0;
void adduser() {};
void initialize(){
   u = (USER *)malloc(sizeof(USER)*20);
   //do all the other initializations here
}
int main(){
   initialize();
   return 0;
}
```